# pyqt & pyside multithreading all stop

Tags: multithreading, pyqt

it got me crazy as I just started using QThread. 
Here is a short program to test using QThread.

i want to make all thread stopped when STOP button is being pressed. However just only one thread stop. why this problem is happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the stop button, you just call `self.downloader.stop()`. At this point, self.downloader is the last thread you created, namely Thread-5. So it makes sense that only Thread-5 stops. You have to modify the `stop` slot. Something like this may work:

```
def stop(self):
    for thread in self.threads:
        thread.stop()
```